# how to get vertices of hexagons from the polycollection output of hexbin() matplotlib method?

Tags: python, matplotlib, hex, bin

I am trying to get the vertices of hexagons drawn from hexbin() method using matplotlib and python. Got the no. of points in each hexagon using .get_arrays() and tried getting vertices co-ordinates with get_paths() but it gives me just 1 path (i.e vertices of just 1 hexagon).

How can I retrieve vertices of all the hexagons? The tried code is written below with the output.

```
x, y = np.random.normal(size=(2, 10000))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=20)
paths=im.get_paths()
print(paths)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

[image]

[the output map that is being generated has more than 1 hexagon. I can't upload it here due to account restrictions since I am new to this.][2]

```
 [Path(array([[ 0.18489907, -0.1102285 ],
   [ 0.18489907,  0.1102285 ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.22045701],
   [-0.18489907,  0.1102285 ],
   [-0.18489907, -0.1102285 ],
   [ 0.        , -0.22045701],
   [ 0.18489907, -0.1102285 ]]), array([ 1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2, 79], dtype=uint8))]
```

Comment: What's the problem? it looks like you have the vertices in that path object.

Comment: The problem is that the path array just has vertices of one single hexagon but not for all. I want for all the hexagons.

Comment: But how are we to know that without a minimal, but complete working example?

Comment: I updated the question with full code. Kindly have a look and let me know if you have an idea about it?

Comment: Your minimal example should also include code that generates a minimal dataset. No one but you has this file you're reading.

Comment: I misunderstood by complete working example. Kindly check the question now. I think this should be understandable and executable.

Comment: thanks. that's an excellent minimal example. if you post a link to your image, I'll embed it in the question for you. after that, we just gotta find someone who knows the answer!

Comment: thanks! here is the link to the image: https://goo.gl/photos/N9MN54GVeF75Fggq7  . I think if I get co-ordinates for more than 1 hexagon, it should work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering it myself the way I solved it and it worked.

Step 1: Get the sample hexagon co-ordinates with im.get_paths() as done above in the question.

Step 2: Get offsets of all the hexagons created by hexbin() method using im.get_offsets(). It gives x and y offsets for all the hexagons.

Step 3: Just add the offsets to the sample 'path' co-ordinates obtained in step 1 and this will give the actual co-ordinates of the hexagon collection.